# Sql script to get values for two tables combined

Tags: sql

I have two tables like this:

```
    Table1
    ________
StudentNumbers  ExamType
1234        1
2343        2   
3345        5
3454        1
5465        2
...
    Table2
    ________
StudentNumbers  ExamType      ExamDate  School  Area
1234        1       0825    warren  ny
1234        1       0829    north   nj  
1233        2       0921    north   nj              
2343        1       0922    warren  ny
2343          1                  0925     north   ny
...
```

I need to find out each students maximum ExamDate from the Table2 by using data from Table1 for particular ExamType. I have come up with this so far but this seems incorrect:

```
Select t2.StudentNumbers, t2.ExamType, max(t2.ExamDate), t2.School, t2.Area 
from Table2 as t2
Join Table1 as t1 on
t1.StudentNumbers = t2.StudentNumbers 
where t2.ExamType = 1
```

I am getting error as invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause

It should basically return back:

```
StudentNumbers  ExamType      ExamDate  School  Area
  1234      1       0829    north   nj  
  2343          1                  0925     north   ny
```

Comment: You have Table2 as tl and then go on to reference its attributes as t2.attributeName.

Comment: @JohnSheridan - Sorry posted in a hurry. I updated the query now.

Comment: Wonder if the guys from stackoverflow have thought of 'homeworkoverflow' yet?

Comment: Select t2.StudentNumbers, t2.ExamType, max(t2.ExamDate), t2.School, t2.Area from Table2 as t2, Table2 as t1 WHERE t1.StudentNumbers = t2.StudentNumbers AND t1.ExamType = t2.ExamType AND t2.ExamType = 1   (Also, given that Table2 duplicates the fields of Table1 there is not a lot of point in using Table1 in the query.

Comment: @JohnSheridan - I need exact rows. Query works if i remove max function. But i need to use that max function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `max()` or another aggregate function, the other fields in the result set need to be grouped.

```
Select t2.StudentNumbers, t2.ExamType, max(t2.ExamDate), t2.School, t2.Area 
from Table2 as t2
Join Table1 as t1 on
t1.StudentNumbers = t2.StudentNumbers 
where t2.ExamType = 1
group by t2.StudentNumbers, t2.ExamType, t2.School, t2.Area
```

This will give you the latest exam date per student, exam type, school and area.

Comment: Thanks, this work but is it a right approch? Is it ok to use group by for all 4 variables?

Comment: It depends.  Do you want to group by all four?  If you group by the student number and exam type, it will give you the last date for each distinct variation of those two variables, regardless of school or area.  It depends *entirely* upon what you're looking for.  Note that you can't return the school and area in the query unless you group by them.

Comment: Additionally, I'll add that I've written queries that have grouped by a dozen fields.  Let the database engine handle efficiency for you.  Just code for the logic you need.

Comment: I had to group by all four. Because if i use group by one or two it still gives me that aggregate error.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You can't have any fields in the result set that a) aren't grouped by, or b) not in an aggregate

Comment: Another problem since one field is saved as type image. Above query is not working now if i use max.

Comment: You need to ask that in another question.  My answer did answer your first question, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either `GROUP BY` or change the aggregate to a window function (eg. `MAX(t2.ExamDate) over (partition by t2.StudentNumbers, t2.ExamType)`.

BTW, as mentioned in some of the comments, considering the data in the first table is included in the second , the whole idea of the `JOIN` is not really useful.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong

1. `xxx` is invalid in the select list i.e. there is a problem with selecting column `xxx`
2. because it is not contained in either

   - *an aggregate function* e.g. `MAX`, `SUM`, `COUNT`
   - ***or*** the group by clause e.g. `GROUP BY xxx`

So you either have to use that column in an aggregate function or place the column in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Given that you only need to "find each students maximum `ExamDate` from the `Table2`" and `ExamType` is already in `Table2` then a lot of the columns you are selecting and the join seem to be unnecessary and the query can be reduced to

```
SELECT t2.StudentNumbers
    , MAX(t2.ExamDate) AS MaxExamDate
FROM Table2 AS t2
WHERE t2.ExamType = 1
GROUP BY t2.StudentNumbers
```